# Having issue in wordpress website homepage showing invalid page and not showing url header section

Tags: customization, menus, homepage, wordpress.com-hosting, home-url

Saloni here. My issue is with my WordPress website. Actually, I am working on my website, and in that homepage section, it shows an invalid page in the menu section, but when I open my website's URL homepage, it shows only three pages, such as about us, blog, and contact us, but not home. In the dashboard and pages section, it is working absolutely fine with no errors. So kindly, please help me or anyone fix this issue.[image: Having an homepage invalid page issue] My site is -https://sjcontentwriterblog.com

Comment: If you click the Add Items button, can you add the frontpage again to the list of menu items?